# Calculate the frequency at each sample of a swept sine waveform

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a series of recordings of swept sine audio signals, and I want to know what the effective frequency is at each sample.

For instance the sine sweep might be between 400-10000 Hz, and last for 500 samples.

I'm working in Matlab, and I would use logspace(a,b,n) but it only accepts a and b as powers of 10. I need something that would produce a logarythmically increasing array of values between any 2 values.

Ideally in matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can express your values a and b as exponents of 10, because 10^(log10(a)) = a.

So:

```
 n = 100;        %number of points between a and b
 y = logspace(log10(a), log10(b), n);
```